# Creating a 3-dimensional NMDS plot using Ordiplot3d but struggling to have row labels?

Tags: r, error-handling, 3d, vegan

I am trying to construct a 3-dimensional NMDS plot from outputs of the function metaMDS() with k=3 for data collected on plant species abundance for quadrat samples I took in the field. I have to use `k = 3` for my data in order to return stress of less than 0.2 for statistical reliability. Thus, I need a plot that includes NMDS1, NMDS2, and NMDS3 values. I have successfully created the plot using Ordiplot3d but I cannot add the row labels that label each point on the plot according to its species label. I have taken two approaches to this problem and have run into issues with each method. This is the code for the first method I tried:

```
> #start code
> nmds_r
   A B C  D  E F  G H I  J K L M N  O P  Q R S
1  0 0 0  0 17 0 21 5 3 17 0 2 2 5  3 0  0 0 0
2  1 0 0  3  4 0  1 6 1 21 0 2 2 5  6 2  0 0 0
3  0 0 0  1  5 0 11 0 1 20 3 5 0 3  8 0  0 0 0
4  0 0 2  2 10 0  8 0 0 20 0 8 5 3  0 1  6 0 0
5  0 0 2  2 13 0 14 0 2 15 0 5 1 0 13 2  0 0 0
6  0 0 1  2  1 0  4 0 4 18 0 5 4 1  2 0 12 0 0
7  0 0 1  3  0 0  6 0 1 12 0 4 3 4  9 1  2 0 0
8  0 0 2  0  0 0  9 0 3 17 0 6 0 0  3 2  0 0 0
9  0 0 1  5 10 0 10 0 3 11 0 4 0 0 12 0  1 0 0
10 1 0 1  3 13 0 20 0 2 15 0 9 2 0  9 0  0 0 0
11 0 1 5  0 13 0 11 0 1 11 0 4 0 0  8 0  0 0 0
12 1 0 4  0 13 0 14 0 0  9 0 6 2 0  6 0  0 0 0
13 0 0 3  0  5 0 20 0 1  8 0 4 1 0  0 0  0 0 0
14 0 0 3  0 10 0 12 0 0 16 0 4 0 0 11 0  0 0 0
15 2 0 0  2 20 0 17 0 0 23 0 3 3 2  6 0  0 1 0
16 2 1 0  0 10 0 19 0 1 18 0 5 0 3  1 0  0 0 0
17 1 1 3  0 13 1 19 0 0 15 0 7 0 5  0 0  0 0 0
18 0 3 6  1 17 0 23 0 0 19 0 3 5 9  4 0  0 0 0
19 0 0 1 14 27 0  5 0 0 20 0 5 1 1  9 0  0 0 1
20 0 0 5  0  1 0  5 0 2 14 2 5 0 3 16 0  0 0 0
21 0 0 7  1  9 0 14 0 1 18 4 9 2 2  3 0  0 0 0
22 0 0 5  1 22 0  9 0 2  6 0 3 3 1  6 0  0 0 0
23 0 0 3  5 21 0  7 0 0 19 0 5 0 1  7 0  0 0 0
24 0 0 4  1 20 0  9 0 1  8 0 9 0 0  0 2  0 0 0
25 0 0 5  2 13 0  5 0 1 11 0 5 6 1  0 3  0 0 0
> #where numbers 1-25 correspond to quadrat number and letters 
> #A-S correspond with a species
> pacman::p_load(vegan, ggvegan, ggplot2)
> library(vegan3d)
Warning message:
package ‘vegan3d’ was built under R version 4.0.5 
> #transform by hellinger
> nmds.hel <- decostand(nmds_r, method = "hellinger")
> nmdsB <- metaMDS(nmds.hel, autotransform = FALSE, trymax = 20)
Run 0 stress 0.2205307 
Run 1 stress 0.2254717 
Run 2 stress 0.2311193 
Run 3 stress 0.2327064 
Run 4 stress 0.2488649 
Run 5 stress 0.2293338 
Run 6 stress 0.2338963 
Run 7 stress 0.2338961 
Run 8 stress 0.2311194 
Run 9 stress 0.256673 
Run 10 stress 0.225004 
Run 11 stress 0.2778786 
Run 12 stress 0.23053 
Run 13 stress 0.2205448 
... Procrustes: rmse 0.01256571  max resid 0.04691462 
Run 14 stress 0.2270003 
Run 15 stress 0.2205449 
... Procrustes: rmse 0.01256954  max resid 0.04693748 
Run 16 stress 0.2670743 
Run 17 stress 0.2649389 
Run 18 stress 0.2532969 
Run 19 stress 0.2676348 
Run 20 stress 0.238051 
*** No convergence -- monoMDS stopping criteria:
    19: stress ratio > sratmax
     1: scale factor of the gradient < sfgrmin
> #stress value for above commands returned no soln at 20 = 0.238051
> #want a stress value of less than .2 for reliability, and convergence
> #so I increase dimension number (k) from 2 to 3
> nmdsC <- metaMDS(nmds.hel, autotransform = FALSE, k = 3)
Run 0 stress 0.1389911 
Run 1 stress 0.1389912 
... Procrustes: rmse 0.000247006  max resid 0.000557347 
... Similar to previous best
Run 2 stress 0.1389912 
... Procrustes: rmse 0.0002615369  max resid 0.0006219339 
... Similar to previous best
Run 3 stress 0.1390416 
... Procrustes: rmse 0.004108656  max resid 0.009386405 
... Similar to previous best
Run 4 stress 0.1500579 
Run 5 stress 0.1389912 
... Procrustes: rmse 9.910066e-05  max resid 0.0002073296 
... Similar to previous best
Run 6 stress 0.1389914 
... Procrustes: rmse 0.0002426746  max resid 0.0005084502 
... Similar to previous best
Run 7 stress 0.1445699 
Run 8 stress 0.1445699 
Run 9 stress 0.1688078 
Run 10 stress 0.1630264 
Run 11 stress 0.1389911 
... Procrustes: rmse 5.441613e-05  max resid 0.0001280038 
... Similar to previous best
Run 12 stress 0.1555636 
Run 13 stress 0.1554298 
Run 14 stress 0.1630262 
Run 15 stress 0.1445699 
Run 16 stress 0.1389912 
... Procrustes: rmse 0.0002620518  max resid 0.000630988 
... Similar to previous best
Run 17 stress 0.1399229 
Run 18 stress 0.150058 
Run 19 stress 0.1389911 
... Procrustes: rmse 0.0001149202  max resid 0.0002614364 
... Similar to previous best
Run 20 stress 0.1389911 
... Procrustes: rmse 4.272057e-05  max resid 9.096348e-05 
... Similar to previous best
*** Solution reached
> #run 20 stress now equivalent to 0.1389911, sufficient for my needs
> #the nMDS must now be displayed in the THIRD DIMENSION as a result
> #now will plot data; recall need for 3d
> nmdsD <-scores(nmdsC, choices = 1:3, display = c("species"))
> nmdsD
        NMDS1        NMDS2        NMDS3
A -0.19684402  0.544392687 -0.049081715
B -0.66276201  0.350059101 -0.066020051
C -0.15462785 -0.213568944  0.034086472
D  0.32193124  0.014319659  0.244180808
E -0.13444329  0.066009019  0.138918253
F -1.15616137  0.368656085  0.083195929
G -0.14178042 -0.003080545 -0.040236587
H  0.56437272  1.005863192 -0.131837714
I  0.10746174 -0.153267714 -0.194286497
J  0.02330803  0.005447439 -0.044143612
K  0.11640613 -0.047756914 -0.696215645
L -0.04222918 -0.086975012 -0.022273066
M  0.16466129 -0.017067854  0.314376227
N  0.12452370  0.223883238  0.004836425
O  0.13046807  0.052150376 -0.197741391
P  0.24151276 -0.353449047  0.105264781
Q  0.82386940 -0.499262450  0.270872966
R  0.05704981  0.755486988  0.372359572
S  0.43669108  0.410976456  0.841584351
> 
> #previously I was running into an error where "scores" is not found when I try 
> #ordiplot3d() for nmdsC, thus I added the step with nmdsD <- scores()
> #now I try the ordiplot3d() with nmdsD, and want to include the rownames in the plot,
> #as they correspond with species labels
> 
> ordiplot3d(nmdsD, col = "red", ax.col= "black", pch = 18)
> #which returns the following plot, correctly in 3d
[3d NMDS plot][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/XcvNa.png
> #when I try the following command, it returns an error
> ordiplot3d(nmdsD, col = "red", ax.col = "black", pch = 18, 
+            with(nmdsD, text(labels = rownames(nmdsD))))
> Error in eval(substitute(expr), data, enclos = parent.frame()) : 
  numeric 'envir' arg not of length one
> # or I try the following command, and return the exact same plot, 
> #without any error messages, but still no labels
> ordiplot3d(nmdsD, choices= 1:3, display = "species", col = "red", ax.col = "black",
           pch = 18,with(text(labels = data.frame(nmdsD))))
```

I admit I am somewhat of a novice at R/Rstudio (I am using Rstudio if that makes a difference) but have been able to resolve any errors that showed up in the past through research on forums and tutorials. This is just so case-specific to my research project that I haven't been able to find a solution on my own.

This is the second method I tried to get around the label issue:

```
> #start code
> #starting from line (everything the same as above until this line):
> #run 20 stress now equivalent to 0.1389911, sufficient for my needs
> #the nMDS must now be displayed in the THIRD DIMENSION as a result
> #now will plot data; recall need for 3d
> #want full control with fortified ordination output
> #fort3D <- fortify(nmdsC)
> fort3D
     Score Label        NMDS1        NMDS2        NMDS3
1    sites     1 -0.066608512  0.316325288 -0.027107492
2    sites     2  0.397708335  0.333023806 -0.037002145
3    sites     3  0.097225783  0.119102891 -0.211587120
4    sites     4  0.163497133 -0.172904735  0.236538140
5    sites     5  0.046138222 -0.053830585 -0.004523407
6    sites     6  0.374187841 -0.199702022  0.074201249
7    sites     7  0.348125788 -0.105706193 -0.055399802
8    sites     8 -0.008904867 -0.333317080 -0.285277443
9    sites     9  0.121660331 -0.073159557 -0.090038385
10   sites    10 -0.018662815  0.053804640 -0.014972350
11   sites    11 -0.182178629 -0.029592443 -0.100554826
12   sites    12 -0.189887074  0.030404030  0.052684176
13   sites    13 -0.294699054 -0.165786744  0.009314810
14   sites    14 -0.113667476 -0.017969177 -0.168598844
15   sites    15  0.025016476  0.244961336  0.101746955
16   sites    16 -0.187333666  0.225622259 -0.156837599
17   sites    17 -0.381572474  0.120166069  0.024649522
18   sites    18 -0.149675375  0.138431088  0.121704526
19   sites    19  0.152247373  0.133819016  0.226852676
20   sites    20  0.109221193 -0.069262849 -0.356266029
21   sites    21 -0.057563079 -0.097310912 -0.015202738
22   sites    22 -0.029424618 -0.023499124  0.172044881
23   sites    23  0.062078601  0.054217033  0.108131470
24   sites    24 -0.201798083 -0.265234126  0.142139346
25   sites    25 -0.015131355 -0.162601909  0.253360427
26 species     A -0.196844024  0.544392687 -0.049081715
27 species     B -0.662762013  0.350059101 -0.066020051
28 species     C -0.154627854 -0.213568944  0.034086472
29 species     D  0.321931245  0.014319659  0.244180808
30 species     E -0.134443289  0.066009019  0.138918253
31 species     F -1.156161366  0.368656085  0.083195929
32 species     G -0.141780422 -0.003080545 -0.040236587
33 species     H  0.564372721  1.005863192 -0.131837714
34 species     I  0.107461740 -0.153267714 -0.194286497
35 species     J  0.023308026  0.005447439 -0.044143612
36 species     K  0.116406131 -0.047756914 -0.696215645
37 species     L -0.042229178 -0.086975012 -0.022273066
38 species     M  0.164661288 -0.017067854  0.314376227
39 species     N  0.124523701  0.223883238  0.004836425
40 species     O  0.130468075  0.052150376 -0.197741391
41 species     P  0.241512764 -0.353449047  0.105264781
42 species     Q  0.823869401 -0.499262450  0.270872966
43 species     R  0.057049813  0.755486988  0.372359572
44 species     S  0.436691084  0.410976456  0.841584351
> ordiplot3d(fort3D, choices = 1:3, display = "species", col = "red", 
+            ax.col = "black", pch = 18)
> Error in scores.default(object, display = display, choices = choices,  : 
  cannot find scores
> #then I try the scores() approach from earlier to clarify scores and try 
> #replotting, but still run into an error:
> scores(fort3D, choices = 1:3, display = c("species"))
Error in scores.default(fort3D, choices = 1:3, display = c("species")) : 
  cannot find scores
```

So those are the two approaches I have been trying! Let me know if there is any more information I can provide to help answer this, but I am well and truly stuck and have been for about 2 weeks now.

Answer (score 3):

You are very close. The `ordiplot3d()` function uses `scatterplot3d()` from the `scatterplot3d` package and that function gives you what you need. First we have to capture the output from `ordiplot3d()` because that contains the function we need to plot the labels:

```
out <- ordiplot3d(nmdsD, col = "red", ax.col= "black", pch = 18)
text(out$xyz.convert(nmdsD), rownames(nmdsD), pos=1)
```

The `xyz.convert()` function converts the 3d coordinates to the 2d space of the plot so we can use the `text()` function to add the labels.

[image: 3d plot]

Comment: I cannot thank you enough for this answer. this was incredibly helpful and your explanation of using xyz.convert() to convert 3d points into the 2d space is something I was unaware of but will now be very useful going forward.